# SwiftUi - Build a Spinner for MapKit

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

I have a swiftUi view that shows a map with annotations ( dots in a map ) and I have created a Boolean variable that changes from false to true when all the annotations are finished being displayed.
Now in ContentView I have a Spinner that I would like to display while the variable is false and stop when its true.
This variable its a global variable and with the following test I know it changes

```
var doneGettingData : Bool = false {
    didSet {
        if doneGettingData {
            print("The instance property doneGettingData is now true.")
        } else {
            print("The instance property doneGettingData is now false.")
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that if for example in the ContentView if I use
`Text("Did it change  = \(doneGettingData.description)")`
just for testing proposes - Its false all the time although I do see it changing with the print !!
[image]

How should I solve this ? I'm missing something, Any suggestions please ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is not seen all code and places of usage, but it looks most appropriate to wrap that global variable into `ObservableObject` class and use object of this class (by reference of course) in all needed places, as well as have it observed in SwiftUI view to automatic refresh, ie

```
class GettingData: ObservableObject {
    let shared = GettingData()         // << to use in MapKit & in SwiftUI

    @Published var doneGettingData : Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if doneGettingData {
                print("The instance property doneGettingData is now true.")
            } else {
                print("The instance property doneGettingData is now false.")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DemoView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = GettingData.shared

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Did it change = \(vm.doneGettingData.description)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: H i@Asperi . Thank you. I Have done what you have suggested and the variable is changing as expected on the print statement but in ContentView.swift it does not. I have the following in : 
'
import SwiftUI
import Combine
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm = GettingData()
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Did it change = \(vm.doneGettingData.description)")
    }
}'
And it does not change !

Comment: And which one did you change in MapKit? What I wrote about `shared`? Review carefully my answer code.

Comment: I did at least from my interpretation what you have said, so I created the Class than I added to MapView the changes so that the variable gets updated at the correct time ( self.shared.doneGettingData = true) and I added just for trying the demoView and the print is getting changed but the view its false all the time. In the demo view I have ( @ObservedObject var vm = GettingData() )  - so maybe I'm not interpreting your answer correctly ?